# Generalized power rule for $x^\sqrt x$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I need to find the derivative of $x^\sqrt x$. I know how to find it using $\ln$-ing both sides, however I would like to learn how the derivative calculator derived this formula
[image]

Update: using $e^{u(x)\ln v(x)}$ can help yes, but we wouldn't use it for instance in here: [Another example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aw7w1.png).

Comment: Use $u(x)^{v(x)}  = e^{u(x)\ln v(x)}$ and chain rule.

Comment: Yes, it helps, but if we have a complex example such as in the update

Comment: It doesn't matter: in complex case we have complex $\ln$.

Comment: The calculator used [logarithmic differentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_differentiation):  $$f'(x) = f(x) \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \ln f(x)  \text{.}  $$

Comment: @BotnakovN. I think it should be $u(x)^{v(x)}=e^{v(x)\ln u(x)}$ .

Comment: @Soheil, yes, it'was a typo.

Comment: I do not think that this works without this "exponential-trick". How would you derivate $x^x$ without it ?

Comment: @Peter Maybe you can use the limit definition and evaluate?

Answer (score 1):

$$
\frac{d}{dx}[u(x)]^{v(x)}=\frac{d}{dx}e^{v(x)\ln u(x)}=e^{v(x)\ln u(x)}\frac{d}{dx}[v(x)\ln u(x)]=[u(x)]^{v(x)}\frac{d}{dx}[v(x)\ln u(x)]=
$$
$$
[u(x)]^{v(x)}\{v'(x)\ln u(x)+v(x)\frac{u'(x)}{u(x)}\}
$$
The first equal follows from exponentiation trick, the second from the chain rule. In the third, you reverse the exponentiation rule.

Answer (score 0):

You can similarly use [Logarithmic differentiation](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=9z1Dz60mWcQ):

$$y=f(x)^{g(x)}\implies \ln(y)=g\ln(f)\implies \frac{y’}y= \frac d{dx} g\ln(f)$$

Now for the product rule:

$$\frac{y’}y=g’\ln(f)+g\ln’(f)=g’(x)\ln(f(x))+\frac{g(x)f’(x)}{f(x)}$$

Therefore:

$$y(x)=f(x)^{g(x)}\implies  y’(x)= y(x)\left(\ln(f(x))g’(x) +\frac{f’(x)g(x)}{f(x)}\right) = \ln\left(f(x)^{g’(x)}\right)y(x) +\frac{f’(x)g(x)y(x)}{f(x)}$$
Please correct me and give me feedback!